# How can I flag people vandalizing my question with rollback edits?

Tags: support, editing, rollback

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/73406/revisions

They keep removing the game's name from the title which is absolutely essential for the question to make any sense.

Comment: The title is already in the tag, no need to be in the name.

Comment: @gameaddict If you find yourself in this situation, a good question to ask is "Why are people rolling back my edits?". Usually they have a reason, and usually you can find out what it is by asking on meta, or in chat.

Comment: @raveturned I think it is also a good idea for more seasoned users of the site to explain why they're making a certain edit that an OP  might not understand (in the form of a comment that can always be deleted later), instead of just reverting a question four times in a row.

Comment: @Kotsu I agree, this is a great example of why you should fill in the Edit Summary. The first 12 revisions of the post have no commit log, so it's clear there was no communication going on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When the game name is in the tag, it will be automatically added to the title of the post in people's browsers, and it is clear from the tag what game you are asking about.  Therefore, it is a valid edit to remove it from the title.

When you are having a disagreement about the content of a post, rolling back or repeatedly making edits is the **wrong answer.**  If you and someone else disagree about how a situation should be handled:

- Check meta for any relevant policy
- Post on meta if none exists or your situation is unique somehow
- Consult with other users on chat

The common thread here is **get more input**.

Once someone has edited and someone else has rolled back, **you and the other person have already expressed your opinions about the content in question** and further editing/rolling back is unlikely to result in consensus.

If the relevant policy has been made clear, and someone is refusing to abide by it, we can take action against that person or the post as appropriate.  **Even if you think you're in the right,** repeatedly editing, rolling back, leaving confrontational or angry comments, etc, is counterproductive.

Answer (score 8):

To keep titles on the site concise, a practice that we've adopted is to remove game names from the question if they are already tagged with that game name. This way, you can derive the type of content of the question's body from the title, and the game that it refers to from the tags that the question is associated with. Furthermore, the most-used tag associated with the question will be attached to the title of the post in the browser.

Here is how your question appears on the front page:

[image: Snip.]

It seems pretty clear to me from this that the question is about changing your team's mode in Rainbow 6 Vegas 2. As a result, I see no reason to add the title to this question.

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions here:

1. What to do when there's a "rollback-war" or "edit-war" on a post?
   And the answer is to **flag for moderator attention,** do *not* just rollback the edits again and again.
2. What to do when someone edits out the game name from my title?
   And the answer is to **do nothing, that user is in the right, we usually prefer questions without game names in the title to avoid redundancy, since the question will already be tagged with the game name.**